# why the following code works in safari but not in IE6?

Tags: javascript

why the following code works in safari but not in IE6 ? It opens the window but doesnt trigger the alert.

```
    <script>
        function fnOpenChild()
        {
            var openChild = window.open('child.htm');
            openChild.onload = function() { 
            alert("im the child window");
        };
    }

    </script>

<input type="button" onClick="fnOpenChild()">
```

Thank You

Comment: The code should not even run in either browser if you're not calling it.

Comment: What happens if you add the MIME type? `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: @BoltClock sorry there was something wrong with the formatting of the code,thats why it wasnt visible.i have include the html bit..

Comment: @NickCraver I tried ur suggestion but no luck :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this isn't actually an answer, but I really suggest you don't use IE6 anymore, and just go with IE8+.

Afterwards, add code that will warn the user that he/she is using an out-dated web browser. You can detect the browser version using navigator.appVersion

If you want to know why you or anyone else shouldn't use it anymore:

http://www.google.nl/#hl=nl&source=hp&biw=1024&bih=837&q=Why+IE6+must+die

Edit: Aah, I guess you fixed it, but I still suggest you take a look at the link above. :)

Comment: i have been trying to convince people here[work] to stop using IE6 but no luck and I have been asked to do it in IE6. I have got no choice. and NO I have not fixed it, still no alert box.

Comment: Aah, too bad.. Well, I guess they will find out sooner or later. Edit: Aah, I see. I thought you said you did, but you were talking about invisible code. :P

Comment: Here here!  IE 6 is a blight on the community!  (Have you ever tried to deal with z-index on that piece of manure?  It's a NIGHTMARE)

Answer (score 1):

try it!
to move onload event to child.htm

Comment: i wud have but im thinking of passing values from the parent to child window in that function, so i need that function to work in the parent window

Comment: @manraj82, please see my answer, it may be helpful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

IE6 has some... rather interesting issues and it requires some workarounds.  Have you tried googleing, "IE6 window onload"?  http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=183578 seems to have a working suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying `onreadystatechange` as well. IE6 has some issue with onload.

```
openChild.onload = openChild.onreadystatechange = function() { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be two possible work-arounds:

**1. Move the onload script ot the childwindow**

```
**child.htm**
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        alert('im the child window');
    }
</script>
<body>
 ....
</body>
</html>
```

**2. Declare a function in the opener window and call it on the the child's onload**

```
**parent.htm**
<script type="text/javascript">
   function forChildWindow(params){
        alert('im the child window' + params);
   }
</script>

**child.htm**
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        var load = window.opener.forChildWindow;
            var someparams = " param1";
        if(load) { 
            load(someparams);
            }
    }
</script>
<body>
 ....
</body>
</html>
```